# Description: Too much time has passed without sending any data for document

Tags: plugins, themes

I apologize if this isn't the correct place for this, but I've been all over the place trying to figure this out and can't.

Here is the relevant information:

Host: GoDaddy Managed Wordpress(likely the issue according to what I've read)

Theme: Kleo

Plug-ins: Akismet, Beaver Builder, Buddypress, Contact Widgets, Evanto Market, GoDaddy Email Marketing, K Elements, Knowledgebase for Documents and FAQ's, Ninja Forms

Timeline:

I ordered the managed WordPress hosting, installed BuddyPress, installed Kleo, installed Knowledgebase, and then installed Evanto Market.  After installing Evanto Market, I began to receive the error message listed in the title.

Attempts to resolve:

I have attempted to install plug-ins individually, in bulk, via upload, and directly from the repository.

There was a thread on GoDaddy indicating that inserting the following line into the wp-confing.php file followed by flushing the cache would resolve, and so I attempted it.

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');
```

I am fairly new to this, and I am at a loss as to how to resolve this.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a plugin question for the plugin guys (Envanto).

Contact their support people/forum.

BTW, I've never bothered with changing the wp-config.php directives, except for turning on debug during development. And I always install plugins/themes from the WP repository. There are chances of getting bad code from other sources (except a zip that you download from the repository, but that' just an extra step).